# Controller & Page data architecture

Tags: visualforce, controller

Does Salesforce Visualforce page have the ability to show table like this:

[image]

For example, the data is Map, where key is Employee and Value is List of reports.

Table should show which employees didn't fill report for last 3 months.

Report have Look up Field to Employee, and Month field.

**CONTROLLER**

```
podchinennie = false;

    lastMonths = new List<String>();
     lastYears = new List<Integer>();

    for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        String num = String.valueOf(Date.today().addMonths(-i).Month());
        if (num.length() == 1) num = '0' + num;
        lastMonths.add(num);
        if (!lastYears.contains(date.today().addMonths(-i).year())) {
            lastYears.add(date.today().addMonths(-i).year());
        }
    }

    lastMonths.sort();
    lastYears.sort();
    System.debug(lastMonths);
    System.debug(lastYears);

     mrlist = [
            select Id, Name,CreatedById,
                    TERF_MR_month__c, TERF_MR_year__c,
                    TERF_MR_EmployeeFullName__c, TERF_MR_EmployeeEmail__c, TERF_MR_Status__c
            from TERF_MR__c
            where CreatedById = :UserInfo.getUserId() OR TERF_MR_EmployeeEmail__c = :UserInfo.getUserEmail()
            order by CreatedDate desc
    ];
    empsReportList = [
            select Id, Name,
                    TERF_MR_month__c, TERF_MR_year__c,
                    TERF_MR_EmployeeFullName__c,
                    TERF_MR_EmployeeEmail__c,
                    TERF_MR_Status__c,
                    TERF_MR_EmployeeManagerEmail__c,
                    TERF_MR_monthNumber__c
            from TERF_MR__c
            where TERF_MR_EmployeeManagerEmail__c = :UserInfo.getUserEmail() AND TERF_MR_monthNumber__c IN:lastMonths AND TERF_MR_year__c IN:lastYears
            order by CreatedDate desc
    ];

    List<TERF_Employee__c> emps = [SELECT Name, TERF_EMP_Manager__r.TERF_EMP_Email__c  From TERF_Employee__c WHERE TERF_EMP_Manager__r.TERF_EMP_Email__c =: UserInfo.getUserEmail()];

    Set<String> employees = new Set<String>();
    if (!emps.isEmpty()) {
        for (TERF_Employee__c emp : emps) {
            employees.add(emp.Name);
        }
    }

    if (empsReportList.size() > 0 && employees.size() > 0) {
        empMap = new Map<String, Id[]>();
        for (TERF_MR__c mr : empsReportList) {
            for (String emp : employees) {
                if (mr.TERF_MR_EmployeeFullname__c == emp) {
                    if (empMap.keySet().contains(emp)) {
                        if (mr.TERF_MR_monthNumber__c == lastMonths[0]) {
                            empMap.get(emp)[0] = mr.Id;
                        } else if (mr.TERF_MR_monthNumber__c == lastMonths[1]) {
                            empMap.get(emp)[1] = mr.Id;
                        } else if (mr.TERF_MR_monthNumber__c == lastMonths[2]) {
                            empMap.get(emp)[2] = mr.Id;
                        }
                    } else {
                        Id[] arr = new Id[3];
                        if (mr.TERF_MR_monthNumber__c == lastMonths[0]) {
                            arr[0] = mr.Id;
                        } else if (mr.TERF_MR_monthNumber__c == lastMonths[1]) {
                            arr[1] = mr.Id;
                        } else if (mr.TERF_MR_monthNumber__c == lastMonths[2]) {
                            arr[2] = mr.Id;
                        }
                        empMap.put(emp, arr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (empMap.size() > 0) {
            podchinennie = true;
        }
    }
    for (String empString: employees) {
        if (!empMap.keySet().contains(empString)) {
            empMap.put(empString, new Id[3]);
        }
    }
```

**VISUALFORCE**

```
            <table class="interactiveTable" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td> Employee / Month </td>
                <td>{!lastMonths[0]} </td>
                <td>{!lastMonths[1]}  </td>
                <td> {!lastMonths[2]} </td>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <apex:repeat value="{!employees}" var="emp">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!emp}</td>
                    <td>{!empMap[emp][0]}</td>
                    <td>{!empMap[emp][1]}</td>
                    <td>{!empMap[emp][2]}</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
```

Comment: A direct answer is "yes" - you can implement such a thing with Visualforce. Are you struggling with a specific issue here? Have you developed a design for this functionality? What are you looking for as an outcome for this question?

Comment: Hi David! I'm look for code template to show empty cells. Also i can't imagine how to use apex:repeat exactly in this case.

Comment: Just so you know, SFSE doesn't generally provide code for specific requirements. I'd encourage you to add details and show what you have tried to far to avoid seeing the question closed for being [inspecific](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you edit in some code to show how you're using `<apex:repeat>` and what's not working for you?

Comment: David, i added controller and page code to question body. thank you for your replies!

Comment: A description (possibly including screenshots) of what it does *now*, relative to what you want, could help. I've read through all this code and I think I understand most of what it does, but I don't see the specific problem that needs to be addressed.